# HTTP/2.0 with WampServer 3.0.6 doesn't work

Tags: apache, wampserver, http2

I wanna try the new version of http protocol ( http2 ) and specially the server_push function on the last version of WampServer ( 3.0.6, with 2.4.23 Apache version and OpenSSL/1.0.2h  ).

I have activated the http2_module ( ssl module is activated by default ) and configured it to give priority at http2 in TLS and clearText connections.

httpd.conf file :

```
<IfModule http2_module>
    LogLevel http2:info
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
</IfModule>
```

And restart services.

But when I launch the localhost page, a basic PHP script page or phpinfo, the protocol version used by Apache is always HTTP/1.1

I use browsers like Chrome ( version 54.0.2840.99 m ) or Firefox ( version 50.0 ).

If you have ideas to resolve the problem?

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? Add your SSLCipherSuite settings to the question. Specific suites required for HTTP/2. Also sure antivirus software isn't sitting in the middle and downgrading you to HTTP/1.1?

Comment: I use http ( h2c ) for the moment, not https.  For the antivirus, Iam sure, I have desactivated it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No browser supports HTTP/2 without HTTPS (h2c) so you must use TLS for HTTP/2.
https://http2.github.io/faq/#does-http2-require-encryption

Additionally HTTP/2 requires strong encryption so as well as TLS you need to ensure you are not using these ciphers: https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#BadCipherSuites

Comment: Oki, I have use TLS with a strong encryption and the problem is solved. Thanks BazzaDP!